# Can't find Crypto library from MS Visual Code's pylint but can from command line

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running an `env` a Python-based project.

I've installed `pycryptodome` and can see `env\lib\site-packages\Crypto`

From the cmd line I can run Python 3.7 and **successfully** enter:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

But when I launch MS Visual Studio Code and enter the same line in a .py file the pylint extension complains to the effect: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'`. If I run the code I get the same error.

I've launched code.exe from within my `env` cmd line but I'm guessing it's not using that env.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you change the `env` in VS Code? On the bottom tool bar it should say something like `Python 3.7.2 64-bit (your env name)...`. If it doesn't just click that label and select your environment. If it just says `Python 3.7.2 64-bit` (or similar) you are not in your environment.

Comment: ah ha! I'd used that UI to switch to Python 3.7. I hadn't realised that 'env' appears here too. simples. thanks.